# How to deal with 'Template' and 'Docstring' simultaneously in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, docstring

What is the standard order of writing a class definition with associated **template** and **docstring**, to make it recognisable by the IDEs ?

Is it:

```
<docstring>
<template>
<class declaration/ definition>
```

Or:

```
<template>
<docstring>
<class declaration/ definition>
```

Comment: The required appearance of any annotated comment is the requirement of the resp. doc. tool which shall be applied. (Concerning your answer, this seems to be doxygen.) So, to answer this, please, have a look at the manual of that tool. Concerning C++, it makes absolutely no difference which order you choose. For the C++ language (and the C++ compilers), comments are considered like white space and handled respectively. They can be used to separate tokens, and don't contribute to the semantic of the  code.

Comment: FYI: [Comments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/comment): _Comments serve as a sort of in-code documentation. When inserted into a program, they are effectively ignored by the compiler; they are solely intended to be used as notes by the humans that read source code. Although specific documentation is not part of the C++ standard, several utilities exist that parse comments with different documentation formats._ and _comments are removed before the preprocessor stage_

Comment: I know and completely agree, What you all have to say. Actually, the purpose of this question wasn't to exhibit the valid position of docstring, but was to choose a position so as to make the IDEs capable of recognising the docstring perfectly and displaying it correctly whenever any user hovers over the respective entity.

Comment: I've edited and made this obvious in the Question, to avoid confusion, hope this pacifies..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way of ordering **template** and **docstring** is as follows:

> - Docstring
> - Template
> - Class declaration / definition

#### Example:

```
/**
* Class of Traveling Salesman Problem : Ctor :-
* @param nov: order of Graph (|V|)
* @param startVertex: Starting Vertex for Hamiltonian Traversal
* @param costMatrix (optional): accepts cost matrix, if not provided, then one should call input() function
*/
template<typename DT>
class TSP
{
    ...
};
```

**Sidenote :** Code snippet behaviour verified on MS Visual Studio IDE